# Test that a function does not throw an error

Tags: swift, cocoa, tdd, swift2

How can I assert that a function does not `throw` an error in `Swift`? In `Objective C`, there's an `XCUnit` macro for this case, but I can't find it in `Swift`.

Comment: Related: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/5824

Comment: Check out this swift testing library: https://github.com/Quick/Nimble You can do things like `expect{ try somethingThatThrows() }.to(throwError())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no specific XCTest function for this, but testing it yourself is pretty simple. Just write your own `do`/`try`/`catch` setup that `XCTFail`s when an error is thrown, as in the developer forums link in @JAL's comment:

```
// generalized to a function
func AssertNoError(message: String = "", file: String = #file, line: UInt = #line, _ block: () throws -> ()) {  
    do { 
        try block() 
    } catch {  
        let msg = (message == "") ? "Tested block threw unexpected error." : message  
        XCTFail(msg, file: file, line: line)  
    }  
}  

// in use
AssertNoError(someVoidToVoidFunc)
AssertNoError("reason", { someFuncThatTakes(parameters) })
```

Comment: As a note, in Swift 3 `_FILE_` has been changed to `#file` and `_LINE_` has been changed to `#line`

Comment: Yup. Seems the kids are all into hashtags these days.

Answer (score 2):

Along side @rickster's answer, if you are using the [Nimble](https://github.com/Quick/Nimble/) matcher, *which I really recommend*, you can write expectations like:

```
expect{ try somethingThatThrows() }.to(throwError())

expect{ try somethingThatShouldNotThrow() }.toNot(throwError())
```